# Do all vector files contain layers?

Tags: vector

[Here](http://medialoot.com/item/vector-infographic-kit/) for example is link to a free infographics. When I open it in Gimp or Inkscape I get a flat image. Is that what should happen? How do you make a use of it?

I work on Ubuntu 12.04. Program I use: Gimp and Inkscape.

Comment: What file format are they in? If they are SVGs, use Inkscape.

Comment: .eps. .svg, .ai. SVG Inkscape is still flat and I don't see any layers.

Comment: They may not have layers.

Comment: Looks like, while there are many objects, they're all on one layer. That's true for the AI version as well as the SVG.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localized (is that not an option on this site anymore?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is **not** mandatory that vector formats contain layers.

Vector files are **object based**. This means objects stack regardless of any layer structure.

It is far more common to find vector files without layers than with layers. This should not inhibit any editing if opened in a vector-based application such as Inkscape or Illustrator. You should still be able to select objects and move or alter them. If you open a vector file in a raster-based application, such as Gimp or Photoshop then the objects get flattened and editing is much more difficult.

As long as you are using the correct application, you should have no problems regardless of any existing layer structure or the lack thereof.

Answer (score 2):

No flattening in my download, works as advertised. Here's once piece of the art selected to reveal the vector objects.

[image]

To clarify, *flattened* refers to vector objects that have been rasterized.

Comment: My mistake. Sorry.

Comment: No problem. That's why GD.SE is here :)